# Installing libssl-dev 1.0.2a on Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to get installed libssl-dev 1.0.2a on Ubuntu 18.04 but to no avail. This version is recommended to install a version a software.

i tried

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev=1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10
```

But got the error below

```
E: Version '1.0.2a-1ubuntu4.10' for 'libssl-dev' was not found
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apt-list -a <packagename>` to see the versions of said package that are available to download. On Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL):

```
$ apt list -a libssl-dev
```

The output is as follows:

```
Listing... Done
libssl-dev/bionic-updates,bionic-security 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.5 amd64
libssl-dev/bionic 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4 amd64
```

These are the versions of `libssl-dev` that are available through Ubuntu's package repository. The version you are trying to install (1.0.2a) is not available for installation on Ubuntu 18.04 using `apt`. If you must have that specific version of `libssl-dev`, then there are alternative ways of installing it. It shouldn't hurt to try one of the newer versions, though.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sam. Really appreciated. The software i'm trying to install gives error installing newer versions and 1.0.2a is the recommended. I would appreciate the alternative ways of installing that specific version(1.0.2a).

Comment: Try using the information from this post to install: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt - I found a package that looks like it will work here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/libssl-dev/1.0.2a-1ubuntu1